# how to attach image to gui created by using Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt

How to put an image on the GUI created by Qt?
The south west part of the screen is empty so I want a picture to be put there on a click of a button but I am unable to use QPixmap and setPixmap. Please help me with this !

Comment: Use QLabel, it have `setPixmap()` method.

Answer (score 11):

Use QLabel in Qt Creator
Then Go to Properties of QLabel
Go to Pixmap
Select the file

Its done.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a QWidget or a QFrame at the place you want to add an image. You can then use the style sheet to set a background-image on that picture. You might want to add your image to your ressources (.qrc).

Using QtDesigner is a good idea for this kind of task.

EDIT :
Here is an easy way to do that without bothering with QPixMap.

```
QWidget *frame = new QWidget(this);
frame->setGeometry(x, y, width, height);
frame->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/path/to/image.png)");
```

The `:` specifies that you want to use the path in your Qt resources. The first two lines are not needed if you define this `QWidget` using QtDesigner.

Also, don't forget to import your `resources.qrc` (however you called it) file (including your resources) and add this to your `.pro` :

```
RESOURCES     = resources.qrc
```

Comment: I have added my picture in the Resources. But still after writing this code in void FF::on_pushButton_3_clicked() function , I cant get the image : QPixmap pixmap(":/home/medha/Desktop/random.jpg"); QPainter painter; . Now what to do ?
painter.drawPixmap(30,251,721,261,pixmap);

Comment: your path `":/home/medha/Desktop/random.jpg"` looks like a path in your file system, you need the path in your resource file. in Qt Creator, open the resource file, right click on the image, in the context menu you can copy the resource file path.

Comment: I tried your way too by changing the path name to the Resources path but still the picture is not coming on the interface! :(

Answer (score 3):

You should use a label (`QLabel`). You can add a label to your form and edit its `pixmap` property in Qt Designer (you will be able to choose one of images you've added to project resources). Also you can set an image on `QLabel` programmatically using `setPixmap()`.